# Show markers on each point of GeoJSON polyline in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, line, markers

I have a line feature and would like to visualize all vertices. I am able to do this in QGIS (see screenshot) but I am wondering how I can do this in my Leaflet map?

[image]

My JavaScript code drawing a simple line:

```js
async function initMap() {

    const map = L.map('map').setView([46.519833, 6.6335], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
    }).addTo(map);

    const trackCanvas = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5
    });

    const response = await fetch(`/tracks/1`);
    const tracks = await response.json();

    const trackLayer = L.geoJSON(tracks[0], {
        style: feature => ({
            color: "#000000",
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.7,
            renderer: trackCanvas,
        })
    });

    trackLayer.addTo(map);

}

initMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this would be to create separate group layer for line points and add point markers to this layer when creating track layer. Good practice would also be to hide points when zoom is to low.

Code for this solution could look something like this:

```
var pointsLayer = L.layerGroup();

var layer = L.geoJSON(geoJsonData, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var coords = [];
    if (feature.geometry.type == 'LineString')
      coords[0] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    else if (feature.geometry.type == 'MultiLineString') {
      coords = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    }
    if (coords.length > 0) {
      coords.forEach(function(coordsArray) {
        var pointsArray = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(coordsArray);
        pointsArray.forEach(function(latlng) {
          L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 2}).addTo(pointsLayer);
        });
      });
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);

function showHidePoints() {
  if (map.getZoom() > 15) {
    if (!map.hasLayer(pointsLayer)) map.addLayer(pointsLayer);
    }
  else if (map.hasLayer(pointsLayer)) {
    map.removeLayer(pointsLayer);
  }
}

map.on('zoomend', function() {
  showHidePoints();
});

showHidePoints();
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a solution using styling but I actually also found a workaround earlier (similar to [TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439615/21355)'s answer):

- create a MultiPoint GeoJSON object using the LineString GeoJSON object
- add to a separate `L.geoJSON` layer
- use the same canvas to render the features

**Note:** I am going to accept TomazicM's answer. His solution can handle LineStrings *and* MultiLineStrings, and hides the point if small scale, and I just learnt about `L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs`.

Anyways, here is my workaround:

```js
function createVerticesLayer(track, canvas) {

    const vertices = {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
        },
        geometry: {
            type: "MultiPoint",
            coordinates: track.geometry.coordinates
        }   
    };

    const markerOptions = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        renderer: canvas,
    };

    const verticesLayer = L.geoJSON(vertices, {
        pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerOptions);
        }
    });

    return verticesLayer;

}
```

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([46.519833, 6.6335], 13);

async function initMap() {

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
    }).addTo(map);

    const trackCanvas = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5
    });

    const response = await fetch(`/tracks/1`);
    const tracks = await response.json();

    const trackLayer = L.geoJSON(tracks[0], {
        style: feature => ({
            color: "#000000",
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.7,
            renderer: trackCanvas,
        })
    });

    const verticesLayer = createVerticesLayer(tracks[0], trackCanvas);

    trackLayer.addTo(map);
    verticesLayer.addTo(map);

}

initMap();
```

---

**Addendum:** Since I have quite a few points to show/hide when zoom level is changed, I use a separate canvas *and* overlay pane which I then show and hide using CSS.

Switching from shown to hidden and vice versa *feels* faster.

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([44.608317, -63.471079], 13);

const detailOverlayPane = map.createPane('detailOverlayPane');

function createVerticesLayer(track, canvas) {

    // ...

    const verticesCanvas = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
        pane: detailOverlayPane,
    });

    const markerOptions = {
        // ...
        renderer: verticesCanvas,
    };

    // ...

}
```

```js
async function initMap() {

    // ...

    updateDetailVisibliy();

}

function updateDetailVisibliy() {

    const displayValue = map.getZoom() >= 17 ? 'block' : 'none';
            
    detailOverlayPane.style.display = displayValue;

}

map.on('zoomend', updateDetailVisibliy);

initMap();
```